# Wpf Main Window Get Minimized

Tags: c#, wpf, window

How can i keep my main window maximized in wpf app.
when i open second window and do something in that and close it, my main window get minimized.
please help me.

in fact i have three window:

- A main window that application start with that.
- A second window that shows a list of entities. with edit, delete and add button.
- The third window that is for editing the selected entity.

when i close the third and second window, my main window get minimized.

i use the below code for opening second and third windows:

```
SecondWindow win = new SecondWindow();
win.Owner = this;
win.ShowDialog();
```

thanx.

Comment: Is there any other code that might be affecting this? I coded a simple test and I don't see that behaviour.

Comment: thanks for answer. in the second window i have a button that opens another(third) window -"For editing an entity"-. then if you close them. the main window get minimized.

Comment: I've noticed similar behaviour with an application that I'm writing at the moment. I haven't tracked it down yet. I did put a *hack* where I force the main window to `Activate()` when child window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your **problem** is: *`something about how you show Main-dialog not other Forms!`*. Can you provide how Show Main-dialog?

also you can try use `WindowState="Maximized"` on your Main-dialog.

Comment: Hi Rev, My main window is the first window in all wpf apps (MainWindow.xaml) that is specified in App.xaml. also i used WindowState = "Maximized" but the same problem still exists.

Comment: if you didn't change anything for showing Main window! `Maybe do you set any other properties or code in window's. Even do changes in  inheritance of window's`. Somewhere you change something from first state and turn that into this situation.